# Redis 'multi' motivation to use

Tags: node.js, redis

It is clearly seen from documentation that I should use multi for redis queries in a loop, or in often called events or functions.

**Example form docs:**

```
 var redis  = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient(), multi;

// start a separate multi command queue
multi = client.multi();
multi.incr("incr thing", redis.print);
multi.incr("incr other thing", redis.print);

// runs immediately
client.mset("incr thing", 100, "incr other thing", 1, redis.print);

// drains multi queue and runs atomically
multi.exec(function (err, replies) {
    console.log(replies); // 101, 2
});

// you can re-run the same transaction if you like
multi.exec(function (err, replies) {
    console.log(replies); // 102, 3
    client.quit();
});
```

**1) Why should I do it?**

**2) If I call function only once for user request(in web app for example) why I shouldn't use multi?**

Comment: its mostly async behavior in "node.js" part , see `async` module to understand why async is a must and life-saver in many situations, `multi` as redis command givens the power to run multiple commands with one single enter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use multi because:

- it opens a redis transaction: all the queries will be processed one after the other without other queries sent from another redis client being executed between (a multi is atomic)
- the data obtained is not in a wrong state, without multi somebody else could have modified the value on redis during the execution of your loop: you could get strange data that have no meaning in reality!
- All the commands are run or none: if you loose connection during the execution of your loop, you could have produced a corruption of data as maybe a write query on a value has no meaning without the writing of another one (which could have failed because of not using multi).